# File not found when loading dataset using Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

so I have written a pycharm project to do kernel regression on a dataset I downloaded to my computer, however, due to RAM issues I have had to switch to Google Colab. Whenever I run my main.py file from the drive, i get the error that it cannot find my dataset file. I've tried updating the directory in which I am searching, however, it still doesn't work. The code is as follows:

```
elif question == "1.2":

    with gzip.open(os.path.join('..', 'data', 'mnist.pkl.gz'), 'rb') as f:
        train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f, encoding="latin1")


    X, y = train_set
    X = X.astype(np.float32)
    y = y.astype(np.float32)


    Xtest, ytest = test_set
    Xtest = Xtest.astype(np.float32)
    ytest = ytest.astype(np.float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also run your whole program in colab. For that you need to upload your datasets file on colab. In order to upload the file on colab,follow below steps:

1. click on the file icon which is present on left side strip of colab
2. then you'll see Upload option, click on it and browse your file. Once you upload your file, it'll shown in files.

To run your program in colab, first you need to change the path of your file.

1. Again click on the file icon, you'll find your uploaded file. Right click on that;  copy your file's path and replace your older path with copied path.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, Thanks so much. I got it working finally, now Colab just crashes for unknown reasons, I changed to the TPU accelerator and it still crashes for an unknown reason. It's a common bug, so hopefully I can figure it out. Thanks. :)